# Retrieving Object from flash immediately after put comes back as null

Tags: java, primefaces, java-8, jsf-2.2

I have the following code XHTML:

```
    <body>
        <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/inc/template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="pagename">
                Home Page
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">
                #{homeBean.message}
                <p/><br/>

            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
```

and I have the following bean init():

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    message= "place holder for now";
    LOG.info("we are in HOME BEAN init()");

    try {            

            LOG.info("before flash insert travelRequest : " + travelRequest);
            LOG.info("Flash map before insert FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash() : " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("TravelRequest", travelRequest);
            LOG.info("Flash map after insert FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash() : " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash());
            LOG.info("after flash get travelRequest : " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("TravelRequest"));
    }
 }
```

It seems like the object I put in the flash is saved in the flash but when I try to pull it out i get a null. Note I have a more code below this little snippet but this snippet of code is what is breaking by giving me back a null for the object being put in the flash.

Here is the log output:

```
INFO  - we are in HOME BEAN init()
INFO  - before flash insert travelRequest : dao.TravelRequest@578c90eb
INFO  - Flash map before insert FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash() : []    
INFO  - Flash map after insert FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash() : [   {TravelRequest, dao.TravelRequest@578c90eb}]    
INFO  - after flash get travelRequest : null
```

So clearly my object is making it into the flash but I cannot retrieve it back. I only get null.

what is happening?

Comment: I feel like this being in the @PostConstruct method has something to do with my problem. I just cannot find any substantiation to my feeling.

Comment: What scope is your bean?  I do agree this is behavior i would not have expected

Comment: @Melloware the bean is ViewScoped.